# Prepared statements, return before closing statement

Tags: php, sql

I have this function here, which globals the $con variable which is the mysql connection variable, topic name is taken by a paramater as you can see. i have created a variable called count for counting the number of rows returned by the statement.

My question is, is using this ok? or there is a better way of doing that?

```
function isTopic($topic_name){
    global $con;

    $topic_name=$con->real_escape_string($topic_name);
    $count = 0;
    if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_id FROM topics WHERE topic_name = ?")){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$topic_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return ($count == 1);
}
```

Comment: Don't use global because this make your code hard to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very wrong, because you do not need to use `real_escape_string()` when you are using `prepared statements` It defeates the purpose of of using prepared statements.

Second, as noted in the comment section, using `global` for getting the resources object is not encouraged, for lots of reason. Instead, you can pass the object as argument for your function, if you are working in a procedural style, otherwise, if you are codding in `OO` style, then you can apply `DI`(Dependency Injection) and get the resources.

I will assume, you are not using `OOP` and provide a procedural answer here.

If you are tying to returns row count just do.

```
function isTopic($conn, $topic_name){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT topic_id FROM topics WHERE topic_name = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $topic_name);
                $stmt->execute();
         return $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Comment: Is closing the $stmt necessary?

Comment: @OrelBitton It is as necessary as closing it in `mysql`. It is arbitrary, not mandatory.

Comment: Wait, if you're telling me that i should've used global, should i create a private variable inside each class for storing the database, and the constructor will take the database as paramater and set it to the class database?

Comment: It depends if you are using `OOP` or not. If you are, then make your properties privates, and inject the resource through your construtor. otherwise, just pass an argument (as shown in my answer) a variable i.e. `$conn` to pass the resource to your query,

Comment: @OrelBitton *Regardless of chosen answer, use my query to count rows.* Have mercy on your server and site performance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you must be mistaken. I didn't create any n rows data.

Comment: @Simon_eQ your function gets `$conn` however your prepare uses `$con`.

Answer (score 3):

**WHY WOULD YOU RETURN ACTUAL ROWS OF DATA JUST TO COUNT THEM?**

When MySQL can do this for you:

```
// if you have uniques
SELECT COUNT(`topic_id`) FROM `topics` WHERE `topic_name` = ?;
// if you have duplicates
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `topic_id`) FROM `topics` WHERE `topic_name` = ?;
```

*It's so easy and MySQL returns a number not records, that's one integer vs. an array of data structures.*

**If you need a count use `COUNT()`.**

**PS**: *String escaping with prepared statements = redundancy + fail.*

**UPDATE:**

*If you just need to check for existence of that `topic_name`:*

```
SELECT `topic_id` FROM `topics` WHERE `topic_name` = ? LIMIT 1; // important!
```

Just select the `topic_id` and limit to 1 match. Still 1 integer return.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: They don't what?

Comment: They don't want to count one line, if this simple case needs an explanation

Comment: @YourCommonSense He uses `rowCount`. If he just wants to check for existence... I'll update the example.

Comment: the condition ($count **== 1**) is quite self-explanatory

Comment: @YourCommonSense Edited the answer. See... how easy it would have been to mention this in your first comment. *I sometimes don't see the forest because of all the trees :)*

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite all right. However, there is too much useless code to my taste.

If I were you, I'd make it at least

```
function isTopic($topic_name){
    global $con;

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_id FROM topics WHERE topic_name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $topic_name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    return $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

But if I were myself I'd make it

```
function isTopic($topic_name){
    global $con;
    $sql = "SELECT topic_id FROM topics WHERE topic_name = ?"
    return $con->getOne($sql, $topic_name);
}
```

Comment: I doubt the OP is using unit tests. AFAIK, it's the only reason (although I am not an expert in testing) not to use global state.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: It's messy, is the reason.

Comment: Ok, that's a reason. Assuming it never been messy for me, it's ok to leave it as is.